# select first character before and after an expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that is show in UI as `Some Company Name`, but in HTML it is `Some html text S<!--START CompanyName-->ome Company Nam<!--END CompanyName-->e some html text`. Don't ask me why.

How to select `S<!--START CompanyName-->ome Company Nam<!--END CompanyName-->e`

with Regex in C#? Of course, the `Some Company Name` can be any other company name.

P.S. A pattern can be repeated more then once.

P.P.S. `CompanyName` in comments is a tag.

Comment: I'm asking "why"? It seems like retrofitting a regex based solution over another problem will just compound the problem. Nip the issue at source.

Comment: because of a certain js rich text editor plugin.

Comment: Since these are HTML/XML comments, I wouldn't bother with a regex. I would just feed the string to a parser and get the resulting document's inner text.

Comment: kinda dirty but a simple `replace` would do the trick, too.

Comment: And how to select one character before and after a comment? At the moment of a replacement I don't know what exactly those characters are.

Comment: `string dirtyfix = s.Replace("<!--START CompanyName-->", "").Replace("<!--END CompanyName-->", "");` /edit nevermind, wasnt clear that there could be more chars before and after the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have the company name within a larger piece of HTML and that the company is "delimited" using comments in a weird way like you describe.

[image: Visualization of pattern]

So you want to extract the red text that is "delimited" using the blue text. You want to ignore the green text.

In that is correct you can extract the company name like this:

```
var text = "bla bla S<!--START CompanyName-->ome Company Nam<!--END CompanyName-->e more bla bla";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<begin>.)<!--START CompanyName-->(?<middle>[^<]+)<!--END CompanyName-->(?<end>.)");
var match = regex.Match(text);
if (match.Success) {
  var companyName = match.Groups["begin"].Value + match.Groups["middle"].Value + match.Groups["end"].Value;
  Console.WriteLine(companyName);
}
```

Briefly, you create a pattern that matches the red and blue text and then "grab" red text by adding groups. The groups are then concatenated to create the final result.

If you want to find all company names "delimited" like that in a text you can use the `Regex.Matches` method:

```
var companyNames = regex.Matches(text).Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Groups["begin"].Value + match.Groups["middle"].Value + match.Groups["end"].Value);
```

If you simply want to replace the company name with another name (and without the HTML comment) you can use `Regex.Replace` where the groups have been removed from the pattern:

```
var text = "bla bla S<!--START CompanyName-->ome Company Nam<!--END CompanyName-->e more bla bla";
var regex = new Regex(@".<!--START CompanyName-->[^<]+<!--END CompanyName-->.");
var newText = regex.Replace(text, "ACME Industries");
```

If you want to keep the HTML comments you will have to put the groups back into the pattern and do a slightly more advanced replacement.

Comment: I believe `CompanyName` can vary, so you cannot have it verbatim in the regex.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: The company name is not in the regex.

Comment: `new Regex(@"(?<begin>.)<!--START CompanyName-->(?<middle>[^<]+)<!--END CompanyName-->(?<end>.)")` -- to me it appears twice, but I may be missing something.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: My understanding is the `CompanyName` is a "tag" in the text used to identify where the company name is. The text between the two HTML comments and also the letter before and after are the actual company name.

Comment: I see. You're probably right, it's not clear from the question.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Martin Liversage is right about a tag, I updated my question. I like Martin's answer, the only thing is that the pattern can be repeated more then once in a whole string. I also updated my question with that info.

Comment: The thing is also that I don't really need a company name from html, I need to select it, and replace it with other similar html.

Comment: @kiriz: Added a description on how you can perform replacement.

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove all html comments from the string.
2. Search for the string you are looking for.

---

1. Find the string with comment (probably using this comment as base).
2. Remove the comment from the result.